# Improving evaluation function in tic-tac-toe game - alpha-beta algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, tic-tac-toe, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I am looking for optimal evaluation function to use in minimax/alpha-beta algorithm for developing tic-tac-toe AI. 

I am counting number of circles/crosses in a row/column/diagonal with empty space behind it (with three-in-a-row, there is no empty space). Based on number of symbols in such line, I multiply the separate scores with 10^(counter-1), which results in 1,10 or 100 points. 
I am sure much can be improved, because optimal solution is rarely found and I am having problems using this function in alphabeta algorithm
My question is - How can this function be improved? Small pieces of code and suggestions appreciated.
My code:

```
private int h(int[][] field, int depth, int player) //final score of the node
        {
            if (win(field, 1)) //if human won
                return -1000; //very bad for MAX=computer
            if (win(field, 0)) //if computer won
                return 1000;

            int heuristics = individualScore(field, 0) - individualScore(field, 1);
            return heuristics;
        }

private int individualScore(int[][] field, int player)
        {

            int sum = 0;
            int otherPlayer = -1;
            if (player == 0) //if computer is the current player
                otherPlayer = 1; //other player is human
            else
                otherPlayer = 0;//Vice versa
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) // rows
            {
                int counter = 0;
                bool rowAvailable = true;
                for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++)
                {
                    if (field[i][l] == player)
                        counter++;
                    if (field[i][l] == otherPlayer)
                    {
                        rowAvailable = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (rowAvailable && counter > 0)
                    sum += (int)Math.Pow(10, counter - 1);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) // columns
            {
                int counter = 0;
                bool columnAvailable = true;
                for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
                {
                    if (field[k][i] == player)
                        counter++;
                    if (field[k][i] == otherPlayer)
                    {
                        columnAvailable = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (columnAvailable && counter > 0)
                    sum += (int)Math.Pow(10, counter - 1);
            }
            int counterD = 0;
            bool diagonalAvailable = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) //diagonals
            {
                if (field[i][i] == player)
                    counterD++;
                if (field[i][i] == otherPlayer)
                {
                    diagonalAvailable = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (diagonalAvailable && counterD > 0)
                sum += (int)Math.Pow(10, counterD - 1);
            counterD = 0;
            diagonalAvailable = true;
            int j = 0;
            for (int i = 2; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (field[i][j] == player)
                    counterD++;
                if (field[i][j] == otherPlayer)
                {
                    diagonalAvailable = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (diagonalAvailable && counterD > 0)
                sum += (int)Math.Pow(10, counterD - 1);

            return sum;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You could let your AI look forward one or even two steps, so you could see what chances the user (and then the AI again) has after the AI has made its step (and rate this chances again).
Additionally you could add some stuff, so that the AI tries to trick the user into situations, he can't get out of. This is possible due to the fact that there aren't that many possibilities in Tic-Tac-Toe.

If you want to be really cool you could make a neural network, which learns from some games you play with it, but this is a totally different story.